# Grabbing the first paragraph from a text unit with RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The title pretty much explains it. I'm writing a blog engine for myself with Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.2 and I need to be able to grab the first paragraph from a post (which is stored as a text unit in the DB) to use as a post summary for the front page. What's the simplest way of doing this?

Google revealed very little on this issue; it doesn't seem like a common need.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer becomes rather obvious once you start thinking what exactly defines "a paragraph" in your world.

If it is the first list of characters followd by two newline characters? Something like

```
str.split("\n\n", 2)[0]
```

could work.

If you have HTML and your paragraphs are defined by `<p>` tags, use nokogiri like

```
Nokogiri::HTML.parse(input_string).css('p').first.text
```

But agin, it all depends on how you define your paragraph. And stuff like this most often solves itself once you start thinking about what exactly you want to have, i.e. how to transform the input data to output data in an abstract way. The required algorithm comes naturally from these steps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot. As an Objective-C programmer only having worked with both Ruby and Rails for about a month now, the obvious isn't obvious to me quite yet, haha.

Comment: Well, things like splitting/searching in a string, Regexes, and XML parsers are available about everywhere. Most concepts are more or less the same in every language. They are just spelled differently :)

Answer (score 1):

In case this might help someone, I got the desired result in RoR by combining Holger Just's Nokogiri solution with RedCloth to get the html tags:

```
Nokogiri::HTML.parse(raw RedCloth.new(input_string).to_html).css('p').first.text
```

Answer (score -1):

str.lines[0] should give you the first sentence ... or simply use truncate() ActionView Helper if you don't mind splitting in the middle of a sentence